# How to access remote keyboard on remote PC via SSH

Tags: ubuntu, bash, ssh

I have the following scenario:

PC#1 running UBUNTU, PC#2 running UBUNTU

from PC#1 I open ssh (terminal) to PC#2. I want to see in my terminal on PC#1 input from both keyboards (#1 & #2)...

Please help. P.S. I am using bash script...

Answer (score 0):

You should use a "terminal multiplexer like [screen](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/screen.1.html) or [tmux](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/tmux.1.html).

Then you can start a session (say you're using `tmux`) on PC#2:

```
PC#2 $> tmux
```

when you ssh from PC#1 (with the same user you have started `tmux` in PC#2!), you
simply attach to the running session:

```
ssh@PC#2 $> tmux attach
```

Now, both the user on PC#2 and the one on PC#1 (connected through SSH) share the *same* terminal session, and they can see each other inputs and relative outputs.

Obviously, you can start `tmux` via ssh and attach from PC#2. You can also run multiple *independent* session and attach to any or all of them.

I suggest you read the mangpages linked as both `screen` and `tmux` are quite powerful and have lots of uses and customizabile parameters.
For example, with both is (somewhat) easy to create shared sessions that can be attached to by different users, so you don't need to login with the same user both on PC#2 and via ssh.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there are many different ways to do this, but the one I would use is:

create a [tmux](https://tmux.github.io/) session on the host PC#2; connect to PC#2 via ssh; attach to the existing tmux session.

tmux is available for every distro but not installed by default, you will have to install it on PC#2.

Within this solution I see three slightly different cases:

1. both users connect to PC#2 using the same username;

   - user on PC#2 opens a tmux using `tmux` command
   - user on PC#1 connects via ssh on PC#2 using the same username as PC#2 user, and joins the session using `tmux attach` command
2. they connect to PC#2 with different usernames and is ok for an user to have access to the other user's files;

   - user on PC#2 creates a group including his own username and the username of the other user on PC#2, for example using:

   `groupadd temporaryGroup`

   `usermod -a -G temporaryGroup usernameOfHisUser`

   `usermod -a -G temporaryGroup usernameOfOtherUser`

   - user on PC#2 opens a tmux using `tmux -S /tmp/tmux_someKnownName` command;
   - user on PC#2 transfer the group ownership of `/tmp/tmux_someKnownName` to the newly created group, for example using:

   `chgrp temporaryGroup /tmp/tmux_someKnownName`

   - user on PC#1 connects via ssh to PC#2 and attaches to the existing tmux session using:

   `tmux -S /tmp/tmux_someKnownName attach`
3. they connect to PC#2 and they don't want to let the other user use their rights.

   - as in the first case but creating a new user ad-hoc for this connection

Now they share a terminal and can see also what gets typed in this console by the other person.